# Best IDE for various languages/ Alternatives to Eclipse?

Tags: ide, cross-platform

Languages: C++, C#, Haskell, Java,  Python, JavaScript, jQuery, Kotlin. 
For a Windows 7 laptop with an i3 3110m processor and 4 GB RAM. So a very lightweight IDE. I plan to use Linux (Solus) in a year or two, so it's definitely a positive if the IDE is cross-platform. Most importantly, it should be free.

Comment: Might help to explain what about Eclipse rules it out of your consideration.

Comment: I would recommend looking [here](http://blog.davidecoppola.com/2018/02/market-share-most-used-c-cpp-ides-in-2018-statistics-estimates/). It has comprehensive statistics of IDEs for various languages.

Comment: @BasilBourque Won't it be super slow on my computer?

Comment: @Pablo I think it's primarily for c++ and c# and it is also very resource hungry.

Comment: @harsh99 This site works by you listing your *specific* needs and constraints. If you don’t know about Eclipse, don’t mention Eclipse. Asking general “best of X list” questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I did try to use Eclipse. I'd been using Code::Blocks previously, and Eclipse was super slow and had lots of errors. I just couldn't get it to work with Cygwin, and when I tried MinGW, it just stopped working totally. VS was better but slower than Eclipse.

Comment: I don't think you can find a lightweight ide for all those languages however you could use text editors like Geany, Atom Code Editor or CodeLite IDE. https://www.tecmint.com/best-linux-ide-editors-source-code-editors/

Comment: @onurcano22 Learning Emacs now.

Comment: Use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) by Microsoft, can compile for gcc-7, python, java, and many more...

Comment: Wondering how an IDE, which suports all that languages at the same time can be lightweight?